# Bulk Update and single Async update with Java,distribuited application

Tags: java, performance, jpa, sql-update, hazelcast-imap

i want to ask you a question about an architecture problem that actually we are facing.

- we have an application distributed across multiple servers
- we are consuming data  through activeMQ.
- we have an object called Price that need to be keep in sync.
- this object can be received multiple times.
- Price has a field called "lastUpdate" and we need to store/update the Price with the most recent "lastUpdate".
- there is no warranties that the last received price has the lastUpdate more recent of the previous.

To keep everything in sync we have 3 ways(we have to use all of them)

- we can receive an async update/insert of the price(using a listener)
- Every 15 minutes we will ask the producer to send to us all the prices that have been changed in the last 15 minutes(scheduledTask)
- Every 1 hour we update ALL the prices(schduledTask)

Tecnologies used:

- ActiveMQ as the bus
- Hazelcast as distribuited map to syncronize before insertion
- JPA

How it works now:
Every time an async price added/update arrive we perform :

this is what we are doing for each price that we want to update/persist(both single and bulk update/insert method call this one)

```
private void priceAddedOrUpdated(Price retrievedPrice)
{
    Date dateInTheMap = hazelcastPriceMap.get(retrievedPrice.getId());
    if(retrievedPrice.getLastUpdate>dateInTheMap(
    {
        //doInTransacion
        try{
            hazelcastPriceMap.lock(retrievedPrice.getId())
            //do some logic including
            persist the price
            hazelcastPriceMap.put(retrievedPrice.getId(),retrievedPrice.getLastUpdate())
        }
        finally{
             //release the lock
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that it takes ages(30/40 seconds) for the tasks to complete while we want to do it in 4/5 seconds(processing an average of 100k prices).
The logic that we are using seems to doesn't have any way to improve the performance.so i think that we need to change the way to keep the data in synch...any suggestion?

edited:

following the suggestion of pveentjer i extended the EntryProcessor class to make it possible to pass the map of prices to be updated in the constructor:

```
    public class PriceEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor, EntryBackupProcessor, Serializable {

    Map<Long, Price> priceMap;

    public PriceEntryProcessor(Map<Long, Price> priceMap)
    {
        super();
        this.priceMap = priceMap;
    }
    public Object process(Map.Entry entry)
    {//get the price from the map for the entry and do the logic/db insertion
```

}

i saw that in the EntryProcessor we can just send the key(s) values.But we use as key only the price.getId().

Comment: Did you measure performance to find the hotspots?

Answer (score 0):

One potential speedup could be to make use of an EntryProcessor.

In an EntryProcessor you get the locking for free since you get the guarantee that no other process is running in the same partition.  The db logic you also move into the EntryProcessor. This would reduce remoting in half.

Are you doing any batching? Because this could make a huge huge difference. So batch like 100 changes for a single partition, once they are received, make use of an entry processor to process this whole batch in 1 go.

Without batching you would have 100 x (1 lock, 1 unlock, 1 get, 1 put)=400 ops. With batching of 100, you would have 1 remote op. So that is 400 times less (ignoring replication).

Comment: thanks pveentjer! i'm reading the tutorial for the EntryProcessor.Indeed it will speed up our update remoting by half!

Comment: Also think about batching. Batching can have dramatic impact on performance.

Comment: In our shared map we store only the priceId(key),lastUpdate(value). We do that to avoid to store too many objects in memory. So the solution could be: create the EntryProcessorPrice that extends the EntryProcessor and has the field Map<Long,Price>. create an instance passing the map with the prices that have to be processed.call executeOnEntries that will perform the update of only the prices contained in the map.

Comment: there is the possibility(or an example)to pass some parameter to the EntryProcessor rather than the only keymap?i need to perform some operation but it has to be done based on the Prices retrieved.

Comment: what do you mean? You can pass parameters to the EntryProcecessor using e.g. the constructor of your self created EntryProcessor class/instance.